# spark-submit command with --py-files fails if the driver class path or executor class path is not set

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a main script as below

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
..............
..............
..............
import callmodule as cm <<<--- This is imported from another pyspark script which is in callmod.zip file
..............
..............
..............
```

**when I submit the spark command as below it fails with Error: No module named Callmodule**

```
spark-submit --master local --py-files C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip mainscript.py
```

**when I submit the spark command with driver class path(without executor class path) as below it runs successfully.**

```
spark-submit --master local --py-files C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip --driver-class-path C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip mainscript.py
                                (or)
spark-submit --master local --py-files C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip mainscript.py
                                (or)
spark-submit --master local --py-files C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip --conf spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip mainscript.py
```

**when I submit the spark command with executor class path (without driver classpath) also it runs successfully.**

```
spark-submit --master local --py-files C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip mainscript.py
                               (or)
spark-submit --master local --py-files C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip --conf spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=C:\pyspark\scripts\callmod.zip mainscript.py
```

Can you explain me where does the below import statement work? on driver or executor?

```
import callmodule as cm
```

Why is the code not failing with Error: No Module Named callmodule when only the driver classpath is set or only the executor classpath is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `--master local`, so the driver is the same as the executor. Therefore, setting classpath on either driver or executor produces the same behaviour, and neither would cause an error.

Comment: even in local mode, will not the driver and executor run on separate jvm? in that case executor wont be able to recognize driver's classpath and viceversa. isn't it?

Comment: @shankar I don't think so. In local mode there is only 1 jvm. The driver and executor are the same thing, on the same jvm.

Comment: okay. got it. So If I have to run the spark-submit job with --py-files option on a real cluster, what is the right one use --driver-class-path or executor classpath or both?

Comment: @shankar I think you'll need to specify both, so that both driver and executors can find the files.